# How do I name and select a group of elements in jquery if they already belong to a class?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-selectors

As title states, how do I name and select a group of elements in jquery if they already belong to a class?

If I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="whateverDiv" class="bigstyle"/>
<div id="whateverDiv2" class="smallstyle"/>
```

Is it then ok to add a class (resulting in the following):

```
<div id="whateverDiv" class="bigstyle slider"/>
<div id="whateverDiv2" class="smallstyle slider"/>
```

In order for jquery to select all sliders by means of `$('.slider')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem with that. It should work just fine.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeYwC/) with demo.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems you don't understand css and very well. Try reading some tutorials or books about the subject.

`class="bigstyle slider"` means you add both the bigstyle and slider class to an element

`$('.slider')` then gives back all elements that have the slider class. So the answer is.. yes it's perfectly ok and kind-of trival as well..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly valid to have multiple classes assigned to an element. Any jQuery selectors will work on individual classes so they can be used soley as a means to select certain DOM elements.

***However*** just to be pedantic, your `ID`'s must be unique, (unlike the code you've posted) or it will cause you some problems.

Comment: I also saw the ids being the same but he was updating his example on the fly. now the id's in the example are unique

Comment: Super quickness all round it seems!